# Use updatepanel to load child page without page refresh

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

This is my Default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)
        ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(HyperLink1)
    End Sub
    </script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Panel Created"></asp:Label>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="Default2.aspx" ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want that when a user clicks on the HyperLink , content from another .aspx page  gets loaded in the Default.aspx without full page refresh

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 0):

You can manually update your updatepanel from javascript.

Here you have the example:

[How to refresh an UpdatePanel from javascript](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/06/26/how-to-refresh-an-updatepanel-from-javascript.aspx)